# Tabulate row values as column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Convert Rows values to columns values in SQL Server
I need to convert example Table1 to Table2 in SQL Server. Other solutions shows a separate column for each server value, resulting in separate columns for each Server A, B, C and D respectively. Instead, if B was the only server, I need that displayed in column Server1 not column ServerB, as indicated by a suggested solution. Any help or guidance would be appreciated:

TABLE1

```
Room  |  Server
1     |  A
2     |  B
3     |  C
4     |  A
4     |  B
5     |  C
6     |  A
6     |  B
6     |  C
7     |  D
```

TABLE2

```
Room  |  Server1 | Server2 | Server3
1     | A       
2     | B       
3     | C        |  C       
4     | A        |  B   
5     | C       
6     | A        |  B      |  C
7     | D
```

Comment: You mean PIVOT? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Why does room 3 get "C" twice?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo

Answer (score 0):

You want to list the values horizontally.  For this, you need to pivot the data, but there is no column for the pivot.  You can generate one using `row_number()`.  I prefer to do pivots using conditional aggregation:

```
select room,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then server end) as server_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then server end) as server_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then server end) as server_3
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by room order by server) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by room;
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate both your help.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon, I tend to prefer conditional aggregations.  However, if you need to go dynamic

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Server'+cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By Room Order by Server) as varchar(25))) From YourTable For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Room],' + @SQL + '
  From  (Select Room,Server,Col=''Server''+cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By Room Order by Server) as varchar(25)) from YourTable) A
 Pivot (Max([Server]) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT - If it helps, the SQL generated is a follow:**

```
 Select [Room],[Server1],[Server2],[Server3]
  From  (
         Select Room
               ,Server
               ,Col='Server'+cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By Room Order by Server) as varchar(25)) 
         From YourTable
        ) A
  Pivot (Max([Server]) For [Col] in ([Server1],[Server2],[Server3]) ) p
```